# jquery mask plugin range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [MASKED INPUT PLUGIN](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) but my problem is, how I can define range for number. For example:

- define 01 to 12 for month?
- define 01 to 31 for day?

My code is:

```
 $("textbox").mask("99/99/9999")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Aren't you doing it now? `9/9/99` will be like `4/9/14`, `99/99/9999` will masks `04/09/2014` (depending on your time format)

Comment: @Justinas when i use this patern , plugin accept this data 2014/99/99